# Bringing Previous month data as a column in bigquery

Tags: sql

First time here.
I have a table that has a Month column as 2022-08-01 for example and then other columns with the monthly result. Like this

| Month | KPI |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 50 |
| 2022-07-01 | 45 |

I need to bring to the same table the data for that result but for the previous month. For example:

| Month | KPI | KPI last month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 50 | 45 |
| 2022-07-01 | 45 | NULL |

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If your particular database support it, you may use the `LAG()` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT Month, KPI, LAG(KPI) OVER (ORDER BY Month) AS "KPI last month"
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Month DESC;
```